# Url Rewriting on Search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a search box on my page (.cshtml) with 3 drop down boxes (Country, State, City). When I click on Search button, the URL needs to be changed to like below.

http://localhost:1234/OrderHistory/Orders (default)

When I click on search with values in dropdowns, the url is to be changed to

http://localhost:1234/OrderHistory/Orders/dropbox1val/dropbox2val/dropbox3val

How to rewriting in asp.net mvc 4?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refine your URL Scheme in the `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)`method. I think somethink like the following might give you a clue.

`routes.MapRoute("RouteName", "Dropdown1{variableNameHoldingTheValue}/Dropdown2{variableNameHoldingTheValue}/DropDown3{variableNameHoldingTheValue}",
new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" }, 
// You might add consrtaints here
);`

EDIT:

if you want this URL to be your default

http://localhost:1234/OrderHistory/Orders (default)

`routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "OrderHistory", action = "Orders", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);`

Comment: Okay. So on click of Search button, I will have to form RouteLink as `Orders\dropdown1\dropdown2\dropdown3` ? Is there a better way to access these id values from `action` otherthan passing 3 optional parameters?